# Visual Force Button Problem in Lightning. On Click of Button In Vf new Vf Page is opened. But in Lightning That Page goes out of Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a VisualForce Page In which i have a button.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Click Me" onclick="redirectTo('/apex/NewPage','');return false;" />
```

But in Lightning Experience I want that Page to remain in Lightning Experience . but page is redirecting out of lightning Experience that is there is no Lightning Header and tabs in that page.

Is there any workaround so that onclick new page Should remain in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found its solution. we can add following functions in visualForce javascript

```
<script>
    function redirect()  {
            if(sforce && sforce.one) {
                sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/NewPage',true);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/apex/NewPage';
            }
        }
</script>
<apex:commandButton value="Click Me" onclick="redirect();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect from Apex controller than this will be handled automatically.