# Refreshing Detail page after calling VF Page from Button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, detail-page

I have a VisualForce page that I call from a custom button on the Contact detail page - it has always worked fine in classic - looks something like this:

**Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="SingleContactProcess" action="{!executeupdate}">
</apex:page
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class SingleContactProcess {

private final Contact con;

public SingleContactProcess (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
this.con= (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
}

public pagereference executeupdate () {
//Run some code that updates contact
    PageReference conPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(con).view();
    conPage.setRedirect(true);
    return conPage;
}
}
```

When I click it the button in Classic, it calls the page, updates the Contact, and reloads the page to display the updated information.

But if I click the button while using Lightning, although it runs the code on the VF page, it does not reload the original detail page. If I manually refresh the page via the browser, I do then see the update data.

Can I make a change to the apex code, or do I need to add some JS code to the page to use the sforce object as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146206/visual-force-button-problem-in-lightning-on-click-of-button-in-vf-new-vf-page-i) e.g.

```
<script>
    function redirect()  {
            if(sforce && sforce.one) {
                sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/NewPage',true);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/apex/NewPage';
            }
        }
</script>
```